# how to change value of all td tag in html via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Heyy i wanna dynamically change the value of all the td tag inside my html using javascript ..any guess hoe can we do it...here is the sample code of my html 
i wanna change its value via javasript how can be do please help..nd thanks in advance...

```html
<h1>Size Conformation</h1>
   <a href="#logoutDialog" data-role="none" data-rel="popup" data-position="window" class="ui-btn-right ui-link" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="logoutDialog" aria-expanded="false"><img class="headerlogo" src="./css/images/icons-png/power-black.png"></a>

  </div>
  <div id="user-details-table" data-role="content">
   <table style="border: none !important; width: 100%">
    <thead>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <th colspan="3"
       style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 20px; color: #7695D8;">Employee
       Details</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td width="40%">IGA Code</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td>IGA001</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td id="username">Vineet Kumar</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td>DOJ</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td>18.04.1991</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td>Male</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td>Base Station</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td>DEL</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="custom-table-for-user-detial">
      <td>Department</td>
      <td class="colon">:</td>
      <td class="custom-table-for-user-detial">AOC</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="white-background" style="margin-left: 20px;"
   data-theme="d">
   <div class="center">
    <form>

     <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c"
      data-iconpos="right">
      <h3 style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">
       Entitlement</h3>
      <div id="sizeable" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 10px; padding: 5px;">Sizable
       Items</div>
      <div
       style="width: 100% !important; height: 1px; background: #dedde2;"></div>
      <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>



       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Shirt</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="shirt" id="shirt" data-theme="a" style="display: inline;">
          <option style="background-color: #fff;">Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>


       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Pent</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="pent" id="pent" data-theme="a" style="display: inline;">
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Belt</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="belt" id="belt" data-theme="a" style="display: inline;">
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Hat</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="hat" id="hat" data-theme="a" style="display: inline;">
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Overcoat</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="overcoat" id="overcoat" data-theme="a"
         style="display: inline;">
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th class="rowleft">
         <div class="flight-from">Cabin Shue</div>
        </th>
        <th class="rowmiddle"><div class="middle-div"></div></th>
        <th class="rowright" style="padding-left: 0px !important;"><select 
         name="cabin-shue" id="cabin-shue" data-theme="a"
         style="display: inline;">
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
          <option>XLarge</option>
          <option>XXLarge</option>
        </select></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rowforspace">
       </tr>


      </table>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  <div class="center">
   <div style="width: 50%; float: right !important; margin-right: 0px;">
    <a class="inner" id="new-joinee-submit" data-role="button"
     data-theme="e" href="javascript:newJoineeSubmit()">Submit</a>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: you can do this with each loop(), here you mention that you have two tables, so go with table id,

Answer (score 3):

> change the value of all the td tag inside my html

Use [getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)

```
vat allTDs = document.getElementsByTagName( "td" );
for ( var counter = 0; counter < allTDs.length; counter++ )
{
   allTDs[ counter ].innerHTML = "WHATEVER YOU LIKE";
}
```

Comment: You have to care about the `HTMLCollection`  returned from `document.getElementsByTagName()` . A `HTMLCollection ` is live, so it can be possible that the value of `allTDs` can change while iterating through the loop and manipulating the DOM

Comment: @OdaYukimura How is that ? Javascript is single threaded, there is no race condition.

Comment: Correct my when I´m talking nonsense. But if you run something like this `a = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); for(var i= 0;i < a.length; i++){ 
document.body.innerHTML = "";
console.log(i)

};` The loop will run exactly one time. Without document.body.innerHTML = ""; it will runs for every `div` in the page. But this is no answer for your question just a code snippet :/

Answer (score 0):

Viva la/le jQuery!

```
$('td').html("<b>Hello table data</b>")
```

I like the native approach from @gurvinder372, but you can't beat a one-liner from jQuery. However, a more functional native approach might look like:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var helloPee = function (p) {
  p.innerHTML = 'Hello P!'
};
[].forEach.call(paragraphs, helloPee);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery code to find the `td` tag and change the text value you want to.
like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#user-details-table').find(' td').eq(2).replaceWith("Changed Value");
});
```

Edited: [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/xasaqof/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Using *document.querySelectorAll* - it is native browser function, no library required.

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("#user-details-table tbody tr");
var tds, value,i;

for (i in trs) {
  if (!tr.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
  tds = tr[i].children;
  value = "ilya"; // select it based on row number (i)
  tds[2].textContent = value;
}
```